# What is the etiquette on using comments to say "thank you"?

Tags: discussion, etiquette

On the one hand, I'd like to thank people who provide useful answers, but on the other, I can see how those comments really just become clutter for everyone else.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The founders of the Stack Exchange network have written about [this exact topic here](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/01/how-to-say-thanks-in-an-answer/).

Comment: +1, and for the TL;DR crowd: **Don't do it!** Upvote, or if you asked the question then accept the correct answer.

Comment: @ChrisS I think you misunderstood the question or the answer. The blog post says `we have a firmly established convention already in place for thanking our fellow users: vote up their post or comment!`

Comment: @kasperd Could you be more specific? `What is the etiquette on using comments to say “thank you”?` => `Don't do it!` seems to make sense to me... maybe I'm in left field.

Comment: @ChrisS But that is not what the linked posting says. It says don't use **answers** to say thank you, it says vote up or **comment** instead.

Comment: @kasperd it says `vote up their post or comment`, it does not say `vote up or comment`

Comment: @ChrisS Oh, the sentence is ambiguous. It has quite different meanings depending on whether you read `comment` as a verb or a noun.

Comment: @kasperd Conceded. However, only voting is mention in the rest of the article. One could infer that "comment" is therefor a noun. I reserve the right to be wrong.

Answer (score 2):

It takes a bit of getting used to but thank you, as well as greetings and signatures, really is just clutter. Of course it might have been different if we didn't have the voting system.

On a personal note, if you ever do feel compelled to post a `thank you`, please, please, please don't abbreviate it to `thx` or some other absurdity. I shudder ever time I see and makes me thing there are too many 13 year olds on the site.

Comment: I'm sad, I'm 15 does this mean I don't belong? :(

Comment: @Jacob, had I not read your age in your bio I wouldn't have guessed you are so young. Your contributions are most welcome.

Comment: Thanks @John Gardeniers, I just disagree with statements like " too many X(teen) year olds" so I try to point it out. :)

Comment: @Jacob, we've all been there before.